# jQuery scroll/follow sidebar (div)

Tags: jquery, scroll, sidebar

used the jquery technique for a scrolling/following sidebar from [Help with Scroll/Follow Sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716795/help-with-scroll-follow-sidebar)

```
$(function() {
    var $sidebar   = $(".sidebar"),
        $window    = $(window),
        $footer    = $(".footer"), // use your footer ID here
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        foffset    = $footer.offset(),
        threshold  = foffset.top - $sidebar.height(), // may need to tweak
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > threshold) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: threshold
            });
        } else if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });
});
```

the only problem is when the sidebar(.sidebar) reaches footer (.footer) it pushes down the footer nearly about height of the footer.
If the height of footer is 200px, sidebar pushes footer to ~200px(Internet Explorer), ~50px(Firefox, Chrome, Opera) then display footer.
 200px of blank space between content and footer is my real problem.
I want the sidebar to stop scrolling exactly where the footer begins.

Comment: so you need to make your script subtract the height of the footer from the window height calculation.....

Comment: Try `threshold  = foffset.top - $sidebar.height() - offset.top`

Comment: @Ashish that extra scrolling was because of the top position of your sidebar, above code removed that from scrolling height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 threshold = foffset.top - $sidebar.height() - offset.top
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a more cleaner code:

```
$(function() {
    var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            }, 400);
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            }, 400);
        }
    });
});
```

You can change `400` with others value to change the duration of the animation (setting it by 0, let the sidebar to "don't" animate).

Answer (score 0):

the question is too old, after i read other answers i make this for my case. i hope this help later people.

```
$(function() {
var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
$window    = $(window),
offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
topPadding = 15;
$window.scroll(function() {
if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
    if (($window.scrollTop())> ($("#following").offset().top + $("#following").height() - $sidebar.height())) {
        ;
    } else {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
            marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
        }, 400);
    }

} else {
    $sidebar.stop().animate({
        marginTop: 0
    }, 400);
}
});
});
```

[image: see picture]